# How to optimise this LINQ Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods

I have this query

```
Dasha.Where(x => x[15] == 9).ForEachWithIndex((x,i) => dd[Sex[i]][(int)x[16]]++);
```

This query is finding that element in `Dasha` whose 15th index value is 9 and if yes it increments dd[Dashaindex][x[16]] value.

Here Dasha is `double[100][50]` and dd is `double[2][10]` and Sex is byte[ ] and can only have value 0 or 1. 0 for Male and 1 for Female

x[15] can only be between 0 to 9 (both inclusive). Same rule for x[16].

It is giving me right results.

I tried optimising this to

```
Dasha.ForEachWithIndex((x,i) => 
{
    if(x[15] == 9)
        dd[Sex[i]][(int)x[16]]++
});
```

This is giving me wrong results. Where am i doing wrong?

My `ForEachWithIndex` is like

```
static void ForEachWithIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enu, Action<T, int> action)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach(T item in enu)
        action(item, i++);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to optimize? Runtime speed? Ease of code reading? Minimum number of characters? Whatever the answer, please give a little explanation for the rationale. Our answers may change depending on *why* you want to optimize.

Comment: Since there are 2 methods (Where and ForEachIndex). I want single function to do that job. so that it do not have to iterate over two arrays. first taken out by where and second for updating by Foreachwithindex

Comment: Is this because of `Delayed Execution`

Comment: On second thoughts, I wasn't right, I didn't realise ForEachWithIndex is your method.

Comment: Let say for 100 data where query runs on all 100 data and takes out 10 data. Now foreachwithindex will run on those 10 data. Means total of 110 iteration for 100 data. Is this correct? If yes my second snippet should just runs on 100 data and do my desired job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save original indexes before `Where`:

```
Dasha.Select((x,i) => new {x = x, i = i})
     .Where(a => a.x[15] == 9)
     .ForEach(a => dd[Sex[a.i]][(int)a.x[16]]++);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a partial answer (too long for a comment) in regards to

```
 Dasha.ForEachWithIndex((x,i) =>  {
     if(x[15] == 9)
         dd[Sex[i]][(int)x[16]]++ });
```

> This is giving me wrong results. Where am i doing wrong?

In the first case you filter the Dasha list of 100 items down to n items, then you iterate over these n items.

in the second case you iterate over all 100 items. So the index will be different, and the value you get from Sex[i] for each row will be different

e.g.

```
 Dasha[0] != Dasha.Where(x => x[15] == 9)[0]
```

unless Dasha[0][15] == 9

Answer (score 0):

Following will give you same result as of first query.

```
    int counter=0;
    Dasha.ForEachWithIndex((x,i) => 
    {
        if(x[15] == 9)
        {
            dd[Sex[counter]][(int)x[16]]++;
            counter++;
        }
    })
```

Comment: What is the use of that counter variable. It is not used except for incrementing its value?

Comment: well it is also used in referring Sex array -> dd[Sex[counter]][(int)x[16]]++;

Comment: ForEachWithIndex is a void function. How can it do yield return?

Comment: you are right. My understanding was incorrect. the return type had to be iterator (IEnumerable, or similar) for yield. Edited the post to remove that section